# Flutter JSON data issue

Tags: node.js, json, flutter, fetch-api, flutter-web

I'm facing issue to fetch json data from Flutter mobile app.

Code as follow:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/pages/main_page.dart';


class App extends StatelessWidget
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Flutter NodeJS",
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
void main(){
  runApp(App());
}
```

main_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/modules/http.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/pages/add_user_page.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MainPageState();
  }
}
class User
{
  String id;
  String first_name,email;
  User(this.id, this.first_name,this.email);
}
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage>
{
  List<User> users = [];
  Future<void> refreshUsers()async{
    var result = await http_get('users');
    if(result.ok)
    {
      setState(() {
        users.clear();
        var in_users = result.data as List<dynamic>;
        in_users.forEach((in_user){
          users.add(User(
            in_user['id'].toString(),
              in_user['first_name'],
              in_user['email']
          ));
        });
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Users"),
        //email: Text("Email"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context){
                  return AddUserPage();
                }
              ));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(

        onRefresh: refreshUsers,
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text(users[i].first_name+"\n" + users[i].email),
            //email: Text(users[i].email),
          ),
          separatorBuilder: (context, i) => Divider(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

http.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import "package:http/http.dart" as http;

class RequestResult
{
  bool ok;
  dynamic data;
  RequestResult(this.ok, this.data);
}
//'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1
//http://192.168.183.179:8081/api/users/
const PROTOCOL = "http";
const DOMAIN = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";

Future<RequestResult> http_get(String route, [dynamic data]) async
{
  var dataStr = jsonEncode(data);
  var url = "$PROTOCOL://$DOMAIN/$route?data=$dataStr";
  var result = await http.get(url);
  return RequestResult(true, jsonDecode(result.body));
}
Future<RequestResult> http_post(String route, [dynamic data]) async
{
  var url = "$PROTOCOL://$DOMAIN/$route";
  var dataStr = jsonEncode(data);
  var result = await http.post(url, body: dataStr, headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"});
  return RequestResult(true, jsonDecode(result.body));
}
```

When I'm fetch json data from "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1". Its working fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp90f.png)

When I try to fetch json data from "https://192.168.183.179:8081/api/users". Its give error:

at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:15340/dart_sdk.js:4348:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:15340/dart_sdk.js:37892:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:15340/dart_sdk.js:37886:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:15340/dart_sdk.js:37718:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:15340/dart_sdk.js:37724:13)
at http://localhost:15340/dart_sdk.js:33243:9

What I'm doing wrong

Regards,
SAO

Answer (score 0):

Check in Postman whether the ip address is returning data.

Another case would be the data obtained, could not be transffered correctly to the app. Check the variables and types where the data is stored.